# Adjusting beer recipes to smaller batches

Tags: recipe, recipe-scaling, software, beer-tools

I would like to starting making smaller batches (10L) but most of the recipes that I have found online are for larger batches. Luckily, it seems that you can scale down ingredients linearly but unfortunately I can't locate this feature in most recipe websites that I have tried so far.

Can you recommend some **free** PC/Online tool that would have a large database of recipes and would allow **in an easy way** to scale down the recipes to smaller batches without me multiplying every ingredient manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brewtoad](http://www.brewtoad.com/) allows you to set the batch size when you're creating or editing recipes. It's not the greatest set of tools, and I find it lacking when it comes to its utility on brewday. With that said it's a decent tool for making and storing recipes, and it's free.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Brewtarget](http://www.brewtarget.org/), which has a scale feature, which works up or down. I use to scale down 5 gal batches down to 1 gal.

It is also open source(free), and works on linux or Windows.....I have both and use drop box to sync the databases.